# ingest multiple json files from ADLS gen2 to ADX through ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-explorer, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm new to both of ADF(Azure Data Factory) and ADX(Azure Data Explorer).
I have multiple Json files in ADLS in different folder level, and I need to ingest all the files into ADX.

```
ex) UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/project1/main/data/json/demo-02/2021/01/28/03/demo-02-2021-01-28-03-30.json
UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/project1/main/data/json/demo-02/2021/01/28/04/demo-02-2021-01-28-03-30.json
UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/project1/main/data/json/demo-02/2021/01/29/03/demo-02-2021-01-28-03-30.json
UserData/Overground/UsersFolder/project1/main/data/json/demo-02/2021/02/23/03/demo-02-2021-01-28-03-30.json
```

I'm just wondering if I need to create as many tables in ADX as the number of the Json files in ADLS.. so if I have 1000 Json files in ADLS, should I create 1000 tables in ADX to copy the data from adls to adx?
and how could I copy the data from adls to adx in ADF?

Appreciate your help in advance

Comment: **(1)** What do you think - 1 table or 1000 tables? **(2)** While ADF is a legit solution, it is not the only one. What were your considerations choosing it? **(3)** Have you read the ADF/ADX documentation?

Comment: I think if I have to create tables then it should be as many tables as the number of json files in ADLS as each file has different data.. and the reason why I chose ADF is because I could use SP there, I don't have access permission to the whole storage of the ADLS gen2 that I'm trying to get data from. Yes I have read the documentations but still need help here

Comment: **(1)** Are the files connected in any way  (business wise)? Are they going to be queried together or separately? Do they have common fields? **(2)** What is the need for SP? **(3)** Why not ask for A read only SAS to the ADLS relevant container/directory? **(4)** There are relevant documents for ADF-ADX combination in both ADF & ADX documentation

Comment: They are connected but should be separated.. but they have data in common fields. The reason why I only can use SP here is because my employer only allows me to access data in ADLS through SP(as we they can set up the folder level access permission). I can't ask for read only SAS neither.. I'm currently going through the documents..

Answer (score 0):

To copy from multiple folders, you can use Additional settings of Copy activity Source. For more information follow this [official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system?tabs=data-factory#file-system-as-source) You may need to use wildcard for multiple files.

Additional settings:

`recursive` Indicates whether the data is read recursively from the subfolders or only from the specified folder. Note that when recursive is set to true and the sink is a file-based store, an empty folder or subfolder isn't copied or created at the sink.

Allowed values are true (default) and false.
This property doesn't apply when you configure fileListPath.
Also refer [Azure Data Explorer as Sink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-explorer?tabs=data-factory#azure-data-explorer-as-sink)

Azure Data Explorer is supported as a source, where data is copied from Azure Data Explorer to any supported data store, and a sink, where data is copied from any supported data store to Azure Data Explorer.  [Integrate Azure Data Explorer with Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/data-factory-integration)

Comment: Appreciate your answer! I will go through the docs you provided. Thanks..:)